# 'utf-8' codec came up in model.dit. can't decode byte 0xff in position 92

Tags: python

I was in the process of testing a test set of quantum neural networks when the 'utf-8' codec came up in model.dit. can't decode byte 0xff in position 92: invalid start byte error, do you know why
I think the problem might be with the random disturbance attack I'm using:

```
def zoo_attack(quantum_model, x, epsilon, max_iterations=100):
    x_adv = tf.identity(x)  # Create a copy of the input tensor

    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        # Evaluate the quantum model's prediction for the adversarial example
        # Compute the perturbation using model queries (estimating gradients)
        # For simplicity, use a random perturbation in this example
        perturbation = tf.random.uniform(shape=x_adv.shape, minval=-epsilon, maxval=epsilon)
        # tf.random.uniform创建随机张量

        # Update the adversarial example with the perturbation
        x_adv = x_adv + tf.strings.as_string(perturbation)
    return x_adv
```

It could be somewhere else

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/qcnn attackt network/my qcnn.py", line 403, in <module>
    validation_data=(test_datas, test_labels)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 395, in fit
    total_epochs=1)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 128, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 98, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 568, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 638, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1611, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "D:\acanda3\envs\tensorflowquantum1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 61, in quick_execute
    num_outputs)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 92: invalid start byte
```

I think it's possible because I didn't preprocess it after adding the perturbation, but I can't preprocess a string tensor